How to prevent Firefox from launching Reader mode when using a USB Barcode scanner to populate form data?
I have a contact form that I want to populate using a USB code scanning device that reads the PDF417 code on the back of Canadian drivers licences. Script works fine in Chrome, but not so much in Firefox. The scanner seems to trigger an "F9" call, which launches Firefox into this Reader mode.
I know I can disable Reader mode in about:config, or use "preventDefault" for an "F9" call, but this seems to skips past the code that actually gives me the scan data.
Here's the code that works in Chrome (slightly modified):
barcode-scanner.js
function scanListener(e) {
    
    // add scan property to window if it does not exist
    if(!window.hasOwnProperty('scan')) {
        window.scan = []
    }
    
    // if key stroke appears after 10 ms, empty scan array
    if(window.scan.length > 0 && (e.timeStamp - window.scan.slice(-1)[0].timeStamp) > 10) {
        window.scan = []
    }   
    
    //console.log(e.key);

    if(e.key === "F9") {
        e.preventDefault(true);
        e.stopPropagation(true);

    }
    
    // if key store is enter and scan array contains keystrokes
    if(e.key === "ArrowDown" && window.scan.length > 0) {
        let scannedString = window.scan.reduce(function(scannedString, entry) {
            return scannedString + entry.key
        }, "")
        // empty scan array after dispatching event
        window.scan = []
        // dispatch `scanComplete` with keystrokes in detail property
        return document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scanComplete', {detail: scannedString}))
    }
    
    // do not listen to shift event, since key for next keystroke already contains a capital letter
    // or to be specific the letter that appears when that key is pressed with shift key
    if(e.key !== "Shift") {
        // push `key`, `timeStamp` and calculated `timeStampDiff` to scan array
        let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e, ['key', 'timeStamp']))
        data.timeStampDiff = window.scan.length > 0 ? data.timeStamp - window.scan.slice(-1)[0].timeStamp : 0;

        window.scan.push(data)
    }

}

// document.addEventListener('scanComplete', function(e) { console.log(":)" + e.detail) })


test.html
<script>
            document.addEventListener('keydown', scanListener);
            document.addEventListener('scanComplete', function(e) { 
                // stuff data into object and populate form fields
            });
</script>

Any help would be appreciated. I've been at this a day and a half already.
Thanks
